# filtering and manipulating rows in df in r

Tags: r, dplyr, lubridate

I have a df which looks like the following:

```
ID Start       End         Contact
1  2022-08-08  2022-08-08  2022-08-08
1  2022-08-08  2022-08-08  2022-08-10
2  2022-08-05  2022-08-14  2022-08-06
2  2022-08-05  2022-08-14  2022-08-13
2  2022-08-05  2022-08-14  2022-08-16
3  2022-08-27  2022-08-31  2022-08-29
3  2022-08-27  2022-08-31  2022-09-01
3  2022-08-27  2022-08-31  2022-09-03
4  2022-08-28  2022-08-31  2022-08-28
4  2022-08-28  2022-08-31  2022-08-30
```

I want to remove the rows where the Contact dates are > than the End date for each ID so that the data then looks like this:

```
ID Start       End         Contact
1  2022-08-08  2022-08-08  2022-08-08
2  2022-08-05  2022-08-14  2022-08-06
2  2022-08-05  2022-08-14  2022-08-13
3  2022-08-27  2022-08-31  2022-08-29
4  2022-08-28  2022-08-31  2022-08-28
4  2022-08-28  2022-08-31  2022-08-30
```

I have tried :`df %>% group_by(ID) %>% filter(Contact <= End)` but this doesn't give the desired output. Please help.

Comment: What does "this doesn't seem to work" mean for you? It doesn't run, it runs but gives you an error (what is it?), or it runs but the output is unexpected (how?), or something else?

Comment: It doesn;t give the desired output

Comment: I find that the simple `filter(Contract <= End)` gives the right result.  The `group_by()` won't affect the result.

Comment: What output, pray tell, do you get?

Comment: The same original df but with one row removed (9 rows remaining). I start with 10 rows and desired outcome should have 6 rows.

Comment: The point of a reproducible example is that it can demonstrate the problem on someone else's computer. I suspect you are running your code on different data with different properties than your example (which runs fine for at least two of us), so we can only speculate about how your real data might be different. Please share an example that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: My df is imported from sql could that be the reason why?

Answer (score 1):

```
df <- clipr::read_clip_tbl() %>% 
  tibble::as_tibble() %>% 
  tidyr::separate(., col = "ID.Start.......End.........Contact", into = c("ID", "Start", "End", "Contract"), sep = "  ")
    
df %>% 
  dplyr::mutate(Start = as.Date(Start), End = as.Date(End), Contract = as.Date(Contract)) %>% 
  dplyr::filter(Contract <= End)

# A tibble: 6 × 4
  ID    Start      End        Contract  
  <chr> <date>     <date>     <date>    
1 1     2022-08-08 2022-08-08 2022-08-08
2 2     2022-08-05 2022-08-14 2022-08-06
3 2     2022-08-05 2022-08-14 2022-08-13
4 3     2022-08-27 2022-08-31 2022-08-29
5 4     2022-08-28 2022-08-31 2022-08-28
6 4     2022-08-28 2022-08-31 2022-08-30
```

Please excuse the hackey way of importing and changing to dates.

Comment: you can use `mutate(across(Start:Contract, as.Date))`

Comment: Thank you.  That would have been better and more intuitive.

Answer (score 0):

It runs fine for me:

```
library(dplyr)
data.frame(
          ID = c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 4L, 4L),
       Start = c("2022-08-08","2022-08-08","2022-08-05",
                 "2022-08-05","2022-08-05","2022-08-27","2022-08-27",
                 "2022-08-27","2022-08-28","2022-08-28"),
         End = c("2022-08-08","2022-08-08","2022-08-14",
                 "2022-08-14","2022-08-14","2022-08-31","2022-08-31",
                 "2022-08-31","2022-08-31","2022-08-31"),
     Contact = c("2022-08-08","2022-08-10","2022-08-06",
                 "2022-08-13","2022-08-16","2022-08-29","2022-09-01",
                 "2022-09-03","2022-08-28","2022-08-30")
) %>% 
  group_by(ID) %>%
  filter(Contact <= End)



# A tibble: 6 × 4
# Groups:   ID [4]
     ID Start      End        Contact   
  <int> <chr>      <chr>      <chr>     
1     1 2022-08-08 2022-08-08 2022-08-08
2     2 2022-08-05 2022-08-14 2022-08-06
3     2 2022-08-05 2022-08-14 2022-08-13
4     3 2022-08-27 2022-08-31 2022-08-29
5     4 2022-08-28 2022-08-31 2022-08-28
6     4 2022-08-28 2022-08-31 2022-08-30
```